# Removing from array is not working - Mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have a document that looks like the following:

```
email:"y@y.com"
playlist:"name1"
IDs:
  0:"5db87297b96b1405403bcf13"
  1:"5dc88666f5ba4a2901062398"
  2:"5dc88666f5ba4a2901062398"
  3:"5dc88666f5ba4a2901062398"
```

The mongo query to remove from an array:

```
    let removingItem = {$pull:{'IDs':'5db87297b96b1405403bcf13'}}
    collection.updateOne({'email':'y@y.com','playlistName':'name1'},removingItem,function(err,data){
        //res.send({'message':'removed'})
        console.log(data)
        client.close();
    })
```

I don't know why this is not working. I also tried with equality:

```
let removingItem = {$pull:{'IDs':{$eq:'5db87297b96b1405403bcf13'}}}
```

For both approach, the output I get on the console is:

```
CommandResult {
  result: { n: 1, nModified: 1, ok: 1 },
  connection: Connection {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      error: [Function],
      close: [Function],
      timeout: [Function],
      parseError: [Function],
      message: [Function]
    },
    _eventsCount: 5,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    id: 0,
    options: {
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 27017,
      size: 5,
      minSize: 0,
      connectionTimeout: 30000,
      socketTimeout: 360000,
      keepAlive: true,
      keepAliveInitialDelay: 300000,
      noDelay: true,
      ssl: false,
      checkServerIdentity: true,
      ca: null,
      crl: null,
      cert: null,
      key: null,
      passphrase: null,
      rejectUnauthorized: false,
      promoteLongs: true,
      promoteValues: true,
      promoteBuffers: false,
      reconnect: true,
      reconnectInterval: 1000,
      reconnectTries: 30,
      domainsEnabled: false,
      legacyCompatMode: true,
      disconnectHandler: [Store],
      cursorFactory: [Function: Cursor],
      emitError: true,
      monitorCommands: false,
      promiseLibrary: [Function: Promise],
      clientInfo: [Object],
      servers: [Array],
      caseTranslate: true,
      dbName: 'test',
      socketTimeoutMS: 360000,
      connectTimeoutMS: 30000,
      retryWrites: true,
      useRecoveryToken: true,
      readPreference: [ReadPreference],
      bson: BSON {}
    },
    logger: Logger { className: 'Connection' },
    bson: BSON {},
    tag: undefined,
    maxBsonMessageSize: 67108864,
    port: 27017,
    host: 'localhost',
    socketTimeout: 360000,
    keepAlive: true,
    keepAliveInitialDelay: 300000,
    connectionTimeout: 30000,
    responseOptions: { promoteLongs: true, promoteValues: true, promoteBuffers: false },
    flushing: false,
    queue: [],
    writeStream: null,
    destroyed: false,
    hashedName: '29bafad3b32b11dc7ce934204952515ea5984b3c',
    workItems: [],
    socket: Socket {
      connecting: false,
      _hadError: false,
      _parent: null,
      _host: 'localhost',
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      readable: true,
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 5,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      writable: true,
      allowHalfOpen: false,
      _sockname: null,
      _pendingData: null,
      _pendingEncoding: '',
      server: null,
      _server: null,
      timeout: 360000,
      [Symbol(asyncId)]: 35,
      [Symbol(kHandle)]: [TCP],
      [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
      [Symbol(timeout)]: Timeout {
        _idleTimeout: 360000,
        _idlePrev: [TimersList],
        _idleNext: [TimersList],
        _idleStart: 11117,
        _onTimeout: [Function: bound ],
        _timerArgs: undefined,
        _repeat: null,
        _destroyed: false,
        [Symbol(refed)]: false,
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 44,
        [Symbol(triggerId)]: 35
      },
      [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0
    },
    buffer: null,
    sizeOfMessage: 0,
    bytesRead: 0,
    stubBuffer: null,
    ismaster: {
      ismaster: true,
      maxBsonObjectSize: 16777216,
      maxMessageSizeBytes: 48000000,
      maxWriteBatchSize: 100000,
      localTime: 2019-12-14T19:20:25.165Z,
      logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: 30,
      minWireVersion: 0,
      maxWireVersion: 7,
      readOnly: false,
      ok: 1
    },
    lastIsMasterMS: 4
  },
  message: BinMsg {
    parsed: true,
    raw: <Buffer 3c 00 00 00 7d 45 00 00 01 00 00 00 dd 07 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 27 00 00 00 10 6e 00 01 00 00 00 10 6e 4d 6f 64 69 66 69 65 64 00 01 00 00 00 01 6f 6b ... 10 more bytes>,
    data: <Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 27 00 00 00 10 6e 00 01 00 00 00 10 6e 4d 6f 64 69 66 69 65 64 00 01 00 00 00 01 6f 6b 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 f0 3f 00>,
    bson: BSON {},
    opts: { promoteLongs: true, promoteValues: true, promoteBuffers: false },
    length: 60,
    requestId: 17789,
    responseTo: 1,
    opCode: 2013,
    fromCompressed: undefined,
    responseFlags: 0,
    checksumPresent: false,
    moreToCome: false,
    exhaustAllowed: false,
    promoteLongs: true,
    promoteValues: true,
    promoteBuffers: false,
    documents: [ [Object] ],
    index: 44,
    hashedName: '29bafad3b32b11dc7ce934204952515ea5984b3c'
  },
  modifiedCount: 1,
  upsertedId: null,
  upsertedCount: 0,
  matchedCount: 1
}
```

Unfortunately, I cannot change the format of the array, or else I would have to change a lot of stuff that depends on this simple structure.

Thank you in advance for the help

Comment: Your output is showing that one document was successfully modified, confirm that the update isn't really happening (you seem to have duplicate strings in that array).

Comment: @IROEGBU The removal is not being done, I checked the documents. There is a document that contain the same style of array with with unique string. Yet unfortunately, the removal still do not work for some reason.

Comment: Can you set it up on https://mongoplayground.net/

Comment: @IROEGBU I will give it a try. How do I show you results when it is done?

Comment: `0: "5db87297b96b1405403bcf13"` This is a sub-document within an array?

Comment: In the doc you have shared IDs does not appear to be an array. It seems to be a object with 0,1,2,3,4.. as properties. Can you share the actual object stored in Mongo?

Comment: its an array I promise

Answer (score 0):

Here is how the `$pull` works with data you are using. Note the `IDs` field is an array of embedded documents. The example:

*Input document:*

```
{
        "_id" : 1,
        "ids" : [
                {
                        "0" : "zero"
                },
                {
                        "1" : "one"
                },
                {
                        "2" : "two"
                }
        ]
}
```

*The Update Query:*

```
db.test.updateOne( { _id: 1 }, { $pull: { "ids": { "1": "one" } } } )
```

*The Result:*

```
{ "acknowledged" : true, "matchedCount" : 1, "modifiedCount" : 1 }

{
        "_id" : 1,
        "ids" : [
                {
                        "0" : "zero"
                },
                {
                        "2" : "two"
                }
        ]
}
```

---

**Updated:**

With the input document:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "ids" : [ "zero", "one", "two" ] }
```

And, the update operation:

```
db.test.updateOne( { _id: 1 }, { $pull: { ids : "one" } } )
```

The result will be:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "ids" : [ "zero", "two" ] }
```

Comment: How would the "ids" in the update query be dynamic??

Comment: Your question is not clear. You mean something like this: `let removingItem = {$pull:{'IDs':'5db87297b96b1405403bcf13'}}`.

Comment: You mean you only know "5db87297b96b1405403bcf13", and not the key (`0`) name to it.

Comment: Exactly, how is the key extracted.

Comment: What are the _input parameters_ you are supplying for the update method?

Comment: I am passing the id (5db87297b96b1405403bcf13) as a value and the item name. By the way, I do not have array of object. They are just arrays of values

Comment: So, the array field is like this in the collection's document: `IDs: [ "5db87297b96b1405403bcf13", "5dc88666f5ba4a2901062398, ... ]`.

Comment: Yes that's how it is.

Comment: Then to remove a particular element use this syntax: `{ $pull: { IDs : "5db87297b96b1405403bcf13" } }`. This will remove the element from the array. If there are multiple instances of the same value all of them will be removed.

Comment: Sorry , but I do not have IDs... I don't  know where it is coming from

Comment: So, what is it you want to delete from the array? Is it an input (or parameter) from an application?

Comment: just a value that's it. I do not have key word associated to the values

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204381/discussion-between-prasad-and-patrick-adjei).

Comment: actually give me a few hours I have to submit this project. Maybe tomorrow, it will still be god to know how to do this.

Comment: You have to know what the document structure is and what operation you want to do. The code I had provided works in _mongo shell_ and I connect to MongoDB version 4.0. Documentation on a [Document](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/index.html) _and_ [$pull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/index.html).